# Macro to highlight rows based on High, Medium, Low Text

Tags: excel, sorting, formatting, conditional-statements, vba

[I have this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVO6b.png)

[I want to first hightlight all the Cells like this based on the text High(red color), Medium (Orange color and low(Green color)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCYzY.png)

[Then I want to sort it like this based on column c and a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN76y.png)

How can we write a macro for this?

Edit after few suggestions:
I tried the recording trick for conditional formatting i am able to get the result. only one part is missing; i am not able to arrange the sequence of High>Medium>Low
It always arranges the table alphabetically i.e. high > low > medium

```
Sub ST03N()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Functional Heat Map"

Worksheets("Functional Heat Map").[A:B].Value = Worksheets("Detailed Analysis").[E:F].Value
Worksheets("Detailed Analysis").Range("N:N").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Functional Heat Map").Range("C:C")

Columns("A:C").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit


With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Range("A:C")
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With

Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2)

With ActiveSheet
.Sort.SortFields.Clear
.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("C:C"), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, _
                     CustomOrder:="High"
.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("C:C"), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, _
                     CustomOrder:="Medium"
.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("G:G"), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, _
                     CustomOrder:="Low"
.Sort.SetRange .Range("A:AA")
.Sort.Header = xlYes
.Sort.MatchCase = False
.Sort.Apply
End With


Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:C" & Lastrow).Select
Range("C2").Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=$C2=""High"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=$C2=""Medium"""
       Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ColorIndex = 44
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=$C2=""Low"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

ActiveSheet.[A1:C1].Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Elementary my dear Watson, using your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have said and without meaning to bandwagon, you could have posted a little more code yourself.  My attempt looks something like this:

I have added a column "D" which categorises the risk as a number using this formula (in cell D2 and copied down):

=IF(C2="High",1,IF(C2="Medium",2,IF(C2="Low",3,0)))

I think this is important to help with the sort, because its hard to sort the words High/Medium/Low and have them come out in the order that you want.  If you do not want users to see these numbers, you can format the cells with a custom format (";;;") which will hide the values of the cells, or hide the column etc.

Assuming all of your data is in "sheet1", then the following code might work.  Its not the slickest code ever, but it appears to do the job for me:

```
Sub dohighlightandsort()

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D" & lastrow).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

readrow = 2
currentrisk = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & readrow).Value

Do Until currentrisk = ""

    If currentrisk = "High" Then
        thiscolour = 255    ' lovely red colour
    ElseIf currentrisk = "Medium" Then
        thiscolour = 65535   ' lovely yellow colour
    ElseIf currentrisk = "Low" Then
        thiscolour = 5296274    ' very lovely green colour
    End If

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & readrow & ":C" & readrow).Select

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = thiscolour
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

readrow = readrow + 1
currentrisk = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & readrow).Value

Loop

' Now that the loop is done, sort the table by risk.

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:D17")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

It basically:

1. Determines the last row that you have used in column A (so it
   knows how big the table is).
2. Clears any highlight from the table
   to "start over".
3. Loops through the rows until the risk in Column
   C is blank (and which point its presumably at the end of the table.
4. Highlights the row based on the risk.
5. When all rows are complete, sorts by column "D" in ascending order, as risk "1" is "High".

I made a lot of this code through recording myself doing stuff as others have suggested on here, and then just edited some cell references to make it "robust" for your use.

I hope this helps!

Paul

Comment: Thanks for this, i already found a bit of help through recording the macro. i have only one issue with my macro which is shared in the OP, could you please help me with it?